# How to effectively copy data from 2D host array (with padding) to 1D device array and remove the original padding in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a 2D column major array on the host with padding, for example:

```
        |1   4   7|
        |2   5   8|
 A_h =  |3   6   9|
        |x   x   x|
        |x   x   x|
```

and I want to copy the data to device memory as 1D array:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} //preferred
```

or

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, x, x, x, x, x, x}
```

What is the fastest and effective way to achieve that using either CUDA and/or thrust?

Edit: I followed the comment of Robert to remove the loop when using thrust but the code only able to copy the first column. How can I make it work for the whole array without using a loop?

```
thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first + rows;
thrust::device_vector<real_type> A_d(rows * cols);
thrust::copy(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(A_h, first), 
     thrust::make_permutation_iterator(A_h, last), A_d.begin());
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in thrust.  The simplest way is to use `cudaMemcpy2D`, of which there are many questions here on the `cuda` tag.  The fastest way may be to just reformat the array on the host and then do an "ordinary" `cudaMemcpy`  (or thrust copy).  Without knowing the exact size of your array and padding, it's impossible to be certain about what will be the fastest way.  Another common suggestion is to send the array as-is using `cudaMemcpy` and then reformat it in device code (with a kernel, or just use it as-is).

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your response. Let's say the matrix A with size N by M and the host padding is 64 bytes. Can you elaborate on "then reformat it in device code"?

Comment: I already knew your matrix was of size N by M.  If you were writing purely host code, and you wanted to reformat this matrix from a padded one to an unpadded one, do you know how to do that?  If so, then write a CUDA kernel that does the same thing.  This would be a very trivial CUDA kernel to write.  You are copying data from an input array that is padded, to an output array that is unpadded.  You can do that on the host side or on the device side.  Depending on the actual values of N and M, one way might be preferred over the other.  Probably wouldn't know for sure without benchmarking.

Comment: Yes, I already wrote a code using thrust to remove the padding but it is very similar to the host code: loop over each column and copy the data up to rows. I thought you propose a new algorithm to " reformat it in device code" in your reply so I can learn. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't ever write loops in thrust code.  A thrust copy operation to copy from the padded to unpadded can be done with a `permutation_iterator` and a single call to `thrust::copy`.  No loops required.

Comment: I tried to remove the loop but the code only able to copy the first column (see my code in Edit above). How can I make it work for the whole array?

Comment: your permutation iterator needs to map indices from the padded array to the non-padded array.  And you can't use this method when copying from host to device.  You can use it for a host->host copy or a device->device copy.  revisit the 3 suggestions: 1. reformat array on host (host->host copy), transfer to device, use on device  2. use cudaMemcpy2D  3. copy array as-is from host to device, then on device, reformat (device->device copy).  regarding indexing, for N=3, padding = 2, you need to arrange a permutation iterator that will map index 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 2 to 2, 5 to 3, 6 to 4, 7 to 5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the use case is only copying a subset of a larger source into a smaller destination which isn't strided (so contiguous), then a conditional copy with a predicate is probably the simplest approach (I guess gather would also work). Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>

struct indexer
{
    int lda0;
    int lda1;

    indexer() = default;

    __device__ __host__
        indexer(int l0, int l1) : lda0(l0), lda1(l1) {};

    __device__ __host__
        bool operator()(int x) {
            int r = x % lda0;
            return (r < lda1);
        };
};

int main()
{
    const int M0 = 5, N=3;
    const int M1 = 3;
    const int  len1 = M1*N;

    {
        std::vector<int> data{ 1, 2, 3, -1, -1, 4, 5, 6, -1, -1, 7, 8, 9, -1, -1 };
        thrust::device_vector<int> ddata = data;
        thrust::device_vector<int> doutput(len1);

        indexer pred(M0, M1);

        thrust::counting_iterator<int> idx(0);
        thrust::copy_if(ddata.begin(), ddata.end(), idx, doutput.begin(), pred);

        for(int i=0; i<len1; i++) {
            int val = doutput[i];
            std::cout << i << " " << val << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the predicate will only select a subset of each column and copy them into a continuous output range:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o subset subset.cu
$ ./subset 
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

If you want something more general (so strided input and output) then you could probably use the same idea with `scatter_if`. As noted in comments, this is trivially done with `cudaMemcpy2D` or a copy kernel.

Comment: In your answer `copy_if` has 5 arguments (and no policy). Is that a mistake?  https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_ga695e974946e56f2ecfb20e9ec4fb7cca.html

Comment: got it https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction_gac1155c0eddf9d5145776bd454732415b.html#gac1155c0eddf9d5145776bd454732415b